# Alamofire, handle void call that can return response with httpError and json body, in Swift 3

Tags: swift, deserialization, alamofire

For automatic response object serialization I'm using example (with some modifications) provided on Alamofire's GitHub page. It works fine for non Void calls. But my Backend API has calls that return just httpStatus code with no response body if it was successful call or with JSON in body if there was as exception on the server side. I was thinking about another extension for DataRequest that will return success(with no data) if httpStatusCode == 200 and return failure with custom error object serialized from JSON for other statusCodes. But I have no idea how to return success with no data. I will really appreciate any help.

```
extension DataRequest {
func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self
{
    let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<T> { request, response, data, error in
        guard error == nil else { return .failure(BackendError.network(error: error!)) }

        let jsonResponseSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
        let result = jsonResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, nil)

        guard case let .success(jsonObject) = result else {
            return .failure(BackendError.jsonSerialization(error: result.error!))
        }

        if response!.statusCode != 200 {
            if let jsonWithException = jsonObject as? [String:Any]{
               return .failure(BackendError.serverException(message: "serverException, statusCode=\(response!.statusCode)", respomseBody: jsonWithException))
            }else{
                return .failure(BackendError.serverException(message: "unparseble serverException, statusCode != 200", respomseBody: nil))
            }
        }

        guard let _ = response, let responseObject = T(representation: jsonObject) else {
            return .failure(BackendError.objectSerialization(reason: "JSON could not be serialized: \(jsonObject)"))
        }

        return .success(responseObject)
    }

    return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

}

Comment: did you find any solution , i am having the same error if response body is void ! Please share if any workaround !